# Create HTML doc like Bootstrap with Prism

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am facing a problem about how to create HTML code examples with Prism, either with pure JS or VueJS.
I need to get something like Bootstrap documentation, with several lines of HTML code displayed, indented, and highlighted.

It works when I put the HTML code directly between the pre/code tags, replacing the < with <.
But I want something more automatic, in which you write a line of code, for example to create a button, and under it, you have the code displayed.

So I am looking for a way to copy this line of code between the pre/code tags.
The problem is that either through the data objects of Vuejs (putting it as a string), or with the appendChild or innerHTML DOM methods, it doesn't works.

With VueJS I get a highlighted line of code but I can't have a multi-line example.
With appendChild and innerHTML, is displayed only the content of the element, for example the text between the button or div tags.

What I need is a way to display all the code, from < of the first tag to > of the last one.
How can I achieve this? Is it possible or is HTML impossible to easily display in the browser?

Here is the easy JS example I am working on.
If you uncomment the line between code tags, you will have the working example, the result I want to get from a more automatic way, just writing once the line of code, and then copying it.
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gg" class="div" data-modifiers='["div--small", "div--big"]'>About</div>
    
    <pre>
      <code id="hh">
<!--        &lt;div class="div" data-modifiers='["div--small", "div--big"]'>About&lt;/div>-->
      </code>
    </pre>
  
    
    <script>
      
      const example = document.getElementById('gg');
      const toDisplay = document.getElementById('hh');
      
//      toDisplay.appendChild(example);
      hh.innerHTML = gg.innerHTML;
     
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution using only pure JS (no framework).

I share the solution if one day someone needs it.

You can add Prism to get a highlighted displayed code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gg" class="div" data-modifiers='["div--small", "div--big"]'>
       <p>fff</p>
        About
    </div>
    
    <pre>
      <code id="hh" class="language-html">

      </code>
    </pre>
    
    <script>
      
      const example = document.getElementById('gg').outerHTML;
      const toDisplay = document.getElementById('hh');

      const regex = /</gi;
      renamed = example.replace(regex , '&#60;');
      
      hh.innerHTML = renamed;
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```